# Amazon S3 file storage via Rest API in C# with roles

Tags: c#, api, rest, permissions, amazon-s3

I'm building a project that will use Amazon S3 to store documents. In particular there are two apps:

- A public facing app will allow users to create and upload documents
- An admin app where you can view documents available and download them

...so the public app should only have 'write' permission, and the admin tool 'read' and 'list' permissions.

The coding for this project will be done with ASP.NET and C#, and the preference is to use S3's REST API. This use case (uploading, listing and downloading documents) seems pretty basic, but I haven't had much luck finding simple examples. Can some you suggest some links?

Answer (score 3):

If you install the AWS SDK for .NET from http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet it will also put down a sample S3 application at C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\Samples\AmazonS3Sample\AmazonS3Sample that will show the basic CRUD operations for S3.

As far as permissions go you should take a look at Identity and Access Management with AWS, http://aws.amazon.com/iam/.  Using this service you can create different users with profiles that restrict access.  So you could create one user for your public application that only has write access and even restrict write to a specific S3 bucket.  Then create another user for admin application that has more admin permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I was hoping to learn how to do these operations with the REST API though. I only need one of the AWS services (S3), and only a couple of it's functions, so it seems overkill to bring in the entire AWS SDK. Also multiple developers are working on this project and I want to avoid complications caused by plugins and getting everyone's workspaces running identically.

Thanks for the tip on IAM. I've noticed the S3 Management Console lets you get into a property page where you can set permissions and bucket policies. Is this essentially the same functionality?